# Call requestPermissions from Asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I'm trying to request permissions from `AsyncTask` called by a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

On `doInBackground` method has this piece of code

```
     int hasWriteContactsPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Context)ctx,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

        if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((AppCompatActivity)ctx,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                showMessageOKCancel("Necessary permissions", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }

           /******** PROBLEM
     requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

*************/
            return;
        }
```

Calling requestPermissions through AppCompatActivity is not valid for me because i need to catch `onRequestPermissionsResult` in `Fragment`, not in `Activity`

The problem is that requestPermissions says this error:

```
Cannot resolve method requestPermissions
```

How can i call `requestPermissions` method from `Asynctask` to catch the result on the caller Fragment?

Comment: AsyncTask's `doInBackgrounnd()` method runs in background. It does not have a handler of UI thread. So it cannot display the dialog. Use it in `onPreExecute()` method before starting your background thread.

Comment: @RRR it call onRequestPermissionsResult parent Activity. I need to catch onRequestPermissionsResult on Fragment

Answer (score 4):

Actually you cannot ask for permission inside the doInBackground method, because as the name says, it is doing work in backgorund, and requesting permissions to the user needs to use UI thread. I suggest to you calling a request permission like this:

```
    public void checkPermissions() {
    final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}

    if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS )
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS )){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Permission Needed");
            builder.setMessage("You must accept the permission.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.global_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ConfigurarActivity.this,
                            permissions,
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.global_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
    }else{
        //doTaskThatNeedThePermission can be async
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can execute `requestPermissions` if you have an Activity reference

```
// in your Activity
final Activity act = this;

// onClick
act.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
```